# Accounts only if Balance is Negative for 3 months or more

Tags: sql, oracle, function, aggregate

```
Select * from Balance;
```

It has AccountID, ClosingDate and Balance.

Every Month it get an entry. For Example:

```
AccountID   ClosingDate   Balance
123         1/19/2017     -3.00
123         12/19/2016    -2.50
123         11/19/2016    -2.50
```

Another Account

```
AccountID   ClosingDate   Balance
456         1/16/2017     -3.00
456         12/16/2016    2.00
456         11/16/2016    -2.50
```

Last Example:

```
AccountID   ClosingDate   Balance
789         1/11/2017     -9.00
789         12/11/2016    -2.00
789         11/11/2016    -5.50
```

I want to write a query that generates the list of accounts who are negative for consecutive 3 statement cycles or more. Keep in mind closing date is different for all of them. The query should not pick up the '456' Account Number. There are around 100,000 Accounts who are negative. But whether all of them are negative for consecutive 3 months is what I need to find.

I need the Account Number and Latest Balance as the output. However, if querying the latest balance would be difficult, then just the account number would suffice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dbms supports window functions, use `lead` and `lag` to get the next and previous balances, `first_value` to get the latest balance per accountid. Then get those accounts with the latest balance where the current row's balance, next row's balance and previous row's balance are < 0.

```
with cte as (select t.*, 
             lead(balance) over(partition by accountid order by closingdate) as next_balance,
             lag(balance) over(partition by accountid order by closingdate) as prev_balance,
             first_value(balance) over(partition by accountid order by closingdate desc) as latest_balance
             from t)
select distinct accountid, latest_balance
from cte
where balance < 0 and next_balance < 0 and prev_balance < 0
```

Edit: Explanation of how it works. Let me show it with your sample data.

```
123         1/19/2017     -3.00 --balance = -3.00, previous_balance = -2.50, next_balance = null
123         12/19/2016    -2.50 --balance = -2.50, previous_balance = -2.50, next_balance = -3.00
123         11/19/2016    -2.50 --balance = -2.50, previous_balance = null, next_balance = -2.50
```

- `where balance < 0 and next_balance < 0 and prev_balance < 0`  - The row on 12/19/2016 satisfies the criteria of negative balance for 3 consecutive months for this accountid and it is returned in the result.
- `first_value(balance) over(partition by accountid order by closingdate desc)` - returns the balance as of the latest date for each account.

You can use this explanation to understand how it works for other accountid's.

Edit_2: To get the accounts which have negative balance for 7 or more consecutive months, use

```
WITH CTE AS
 (SELECT T.*,
         FIRST_VALUE(BALANCE) OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNTID ORDER BY CLOSINGDATE DESC) AS LATEST_BALANCE ,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNTID ORDER BY CLOSINGDATE) - 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNTID, SIGN(BALANCE) ORDER BY CLOSINGDATE) AS GRP
  FROM T
  )
 ,COUNTS AS
 (SELECT C.*,
         SUM(CASE WHEN BALANCE < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY ACCOUNTID,GRP ORDER BY CLOSINGDATE) AS CONSECUTIVE_COUNT
  FROM CTE C
  )
SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNTID, LATEST_BALANCE
FROM COUNTS
WHERE CONSECUTIVE_COUNT >= 7
```

Or if you are prepared to write a lengthy query, use the optional parameter in the `lead` and `lag` function to look forward or look back `n` rows. Here you look back and look forward 3 rows each, for each row.

```
with cte as (select t.*, 
             lead(balance,1) over(partition by accountid order by closingdate) as next_balance_1,
             lead(balance,2) over(partition by accountid order by closingdate) as next_balance_2,
             lead(balance,3) over(partition by accountid order by closingdate) as next_balance_3,
             lag(balance,1) over(partition by accountid order by closingdate) as prev_balance_1,
             lag(balance,2) over(partition by accountid order by closingdate) as prev_balance_2,
             lag(balance,3) over(partition by accountid order by closingdate) as prev_balance_3,
             first_value(balance) over(partition by accountid order by closingdate desc) as latest_balance
             from t)
select distinct accountid, latest_balance
from cte
where balance < 0 
and next_balance_1 < 0 and next_balance_2 < 0 and next_balance_3 < 0
and prev_balance_1 < 0 and prev_balance_2 < 0 and prev_balance_3 < 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It is picking up correct accounts. But it is picking up additional accounts who are negative for 1 or two months only. Meaning they were open 40 days ago and went negative only once. But the query picked them up. How can I remove them where they need to match a 3 month statement criteria.

Comment: it is because i was using the current row's value for the first and last rows in each group..try the edited version.

Comment: You are awesome. I am getting the desired output. For my learning purpose though, I was wondering what in the query is checking that the accounts are negative for 3 months or more?

Comment: i included some explanation.

Comment: Great. Lets say I want to change the criteria to get the accounts who are negative for at least 7 months. Then do I need to change the query?

Comment: @Amir .. you can extend the query originally shown or write a different query to count consecutive negative values. i showed both the options which can be extended to any number of months needed.

Comment: You are a GENIUS !!